# Exporting list of an array and a list to csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, export-to-csv

I have found several links that has helped users write lists to csv file in python. However, I couldn't find the solution to the specific list format I am working with. I have a list where each index is in the following form: `[array([x1,x2,x3,x4]),[x5,x6]]` 
and my list has thousands of indexes.
I want to export this list to csv file where x1 is the first column, x2 the second until x6 as the sixth column.
I have tried pandas library as follows. However, this dumps the array in first column and the list to another column, thus providing only two columns rather than the six that I want.

```
td_df = pd.DataFrame(training_data_arr)
td_df.to_csv('DataSet.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Moreover, I don't want my data to be overwritten, every time I run the code. Rather, I want my data to be written from the next empty line in the csv file

EDIT: My data looks like

```
[[[0.004, 0.336, 0.009, -0.212],[1,0]], [[0.24, 0.66, 0.09, -0.2],[1,0]], [[-0.11, 0.16, 0.77, -0.2],[0,1]]...]
```

Comment: Can you show the actual data you have in `training_data_arr`?

Comment: edited my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append to the csv file, open the file yourself and pass it into to `to_csv`, e.g.:

```
with open('CartPoleDataSet.csv', 'a') as f:
    td_df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
```

It sounds like you just want to flatten your data before exporting it.

One way to flatten it is:

```
In []
pd.DataFrame(td_df.sum(axis=1).values.tolist())

Out[]:
      0     1     2      3  4  5
0 0.004 0.336 0.009 -0.212  1  0
1 0.240 0.660 0.090 -0.200  1  0
```

Comment: Issue resolved. Can you please explain, how  `pd.DataFrame(td_df.sum(axis=1).values.tolist())` works? 
Shouldn't td_df.sum(axis=1) be suffice? Why values and then tolist() needed?

Comment: This combines the columns (`sum(axis=1)`) and the turns resulting `Series` of lists into a list of lists (`values.tolist()`) which is reconstituted into a `DataFrame`.